# How to plot the high since the last green candle in 5 minute time frame in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to plot the high since the last green 5 minute candle.

However, I am getting the error:

> Error on bar 0 : Invalid value of length argument (NaN) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0.

```
bar_since = ta.barssince(close > open)
bar_since_p = bar_since + 1     
high_since_p = ta.highest(high,bar_since_p )
plot(high_since_p)
```

Comment: Your code seems to work well. [Check this](https://www.tradingview.com/x/nFuN7yZN/)